# A better solution to handle PHP and HTML <option> logic

Tags: php, html

Wondering if you can show me a better way to handle this logic? I wrote this and am very ashamed of it. Can you show me a better optimized version of this logic?

P.S $result["item"]; returns an integer.

```
$type = $result["item"];
switch ($type){
case "1":
$type_output = '    
<option value="1" selected>Cash</option>
<option value="2">Cheque</option>
<option value="3">Debit Card</option>
<option value="4">Credit Card</option>';
break;

case "2":
$type_output = '    
<option value="1">Cash</option>
<option value="2" selected>Cheque</option>
<option value="3">Debit Card</option>
<option value="4">Credit Card</option>';
break;

case "3":
$type_output = '    
<option value="1">Cash</option>
<option value="2">Cheque</option>
<option value="3" selected>Debit Card</option>
<option value="4">Credit Card</option>';
break;

case "4":
$type_output = '    
<option value="1">Cash</option>
<option value="2">Cheque</option>
<option value="3">Debit Card</option>
<option value="4" selected>Credit Card</option>';
break;
}
```

html

```
<td>
<select style="width:200px;" name="payment_type">
<option value=""> </option>
'.$type_output.'
</select>
</td>
```

Thank you

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be posted on [codereview.se]

Comment: You are asking for a code optimization, you should open your question at [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: No need to be ashamed of it - you made an attempt and are willing to improve it. That sounds good to me! @Mike is technically correct though - this would be better on _Code Review_. However, you seem to have garnered several answers already.

Comment: I apologize Stackoverflow! wasn't aware of Code Review until just now =/ Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use this approach

```
$type = $result["item"];
$type_output = "";

$options =array(
    "1"=>"cash",
    "2"=>"Cheque",
    "3"=>"Debit Card",
    "4"=>"Credit Card",
);

foreach($options as $value=>$text) {
    $type_output .= "<option value=\"$value\"".($type==$value? " selected" : "").">$text</option>\n";
}
```

Comment: Deleting my answer, this is the best option

Comment: This is quite good, but wraps HTML inside PHP strings, which prevents your IDE from understanding the structure of your document.

Comment: @halfer it's right... but, depending on the cases, everyone chooses the better ratio pro/contros. For `[aA]rray` I did knew it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

you could do it this way and only once

```
<option value="1" <?php if ($type == 1) echo "selected"; ?>>Cash</option>
<option value="2" <?php if ($type == 2) echo "selected"; ?>>Cheque</option>
<option value="3" <?php if ($type == 3) echo "selected"; ?>>Debit Card</option>
<option value="4" <?php if ($type == 4) echo "selected"; ?>>Credit Card</option>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're repeating a lot of stuff here. You can do something like

```
<option value="..." <?php if($type == 1) { print "selected"; } ?> >Something</option>
```

This would work, however you're probably better off using a template engine and letting it handle this sort of stuff for you.

http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.html.options.tpl

Comment: +1. I think the `selected` needs to be `selected="selected"` (i.e. valid rather than just working) but agree with the need for some sort of templating (even if it is just PHP).

Comment: both `selected` and `selected="selected"` should work fine: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select though your suggestion may be more consistent with other attributes.

Comment: You're quite right - just checked a simple document over at W3C. I wonder why they removed such a simple mechanism to validate as XML?

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your document:

```
<option value="1" <?php if ($type == 1) echo 'selected="selected"' ?>>Cash</option>
<option value="2" <?php if ($type == 2) echo 'selected="selected"' ?>>Cheque</option>
<option value="3" <?php if ($type == 3) echo 'selected="selected"' ?>>Debit Card</option>
<option value="4" <?php if ($type == 4) echo 'selected="selected"' ?>>Credit Card</option>'
```

Bear in mind that `selected` on its own is invalid, at least in XHTML. You might get away with it in HTML5, but personally I'd do it properly, as above. Either way, make sure you check your HTML output against the W3C validator.

Also, I tend not to wrap large blocks of HTML in PHP strings, as you have done; it is better to use HTML mode and break into PHP where dynamic output is required. This allows your IDE to understand the structure of your document, and allows syntax colouration and auto-complete to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
type_output = '
<option value="1"'.($type == 1 ? " selected" : "").'>Cash</option>
<option value="2"'.($type == 2 ? " selected" : "").'>Cheque</option>
<option value="3"'.($type == 3 ? " selected" : "").'>Debit Card</option>
<option value="4"'.($type == 4 ? " selected" : "").'>Credit Card</option>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function like this:

```
function selected($selected, $current) {
    if($selected == $current)
        return "selected";
}
```

And then:

```
$options = array(
    1 => 'Cash',
    2 => 'Cheque',
    3 => 'Debit Card',
    4 => 'Credit Card'
);
foreach($options as $value => $option)
    echo '<option value="'.$value.'" '.selected($value, $type).'>'.$option.'</option>';
```

Note that the `selected` function is applicable in other similar cases too.

Answer (score 0):

Ashamed)))

```
sel = document.getElementById("select_id");
if($type>=0&&$type<sel.options.length)
sel.options[$type].selected=true;
```

do it onLoad or better onDomReady... or just after you options code. Don't forget to assign an id:

```
<select id="select_id">...
```

if you're controlling an input, then it would be **JUST ONE LINE** of JS:

```
document.getElementById("select_id").options[$type].selected=true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd do it.

```
$options = array(
"1"=>"Cash",
"2"=>"Cheque",
"3"=>"Debit Card",
"4"=>"Credit Card"
);
$type = $result['item'];
$type_output = "";

foreach($options as $value=>$text) {
    if($value==$type){
        $selected = " selected";
    }
    else {
        $selected = "";
    }
    $type_output .= '<option value="'.$value.'"'.$selected.'>'.$text.'</option>';
}
```

Just noticed Chumkiu had a similar answer, but I'll post mine anyway in case this is clearer to some folk than the ternary if statement